# Can someone explain why $\log e^2$ is equal to $2$.

Tags: calculus, logarithms

[image: LOG QUESTION]

This may sound like a basic question but why is log (e^2) = 2. I'm not very good with log questions.

Comment: Yes, it is not obvious. You need to start from whichever definition of $e^x$ that you have, for example, that $\frac{\partial}{\partial x}e^x=e^x$ and $e^0=1$. Then because $\log(1)=0$ and they satisfy the differential equation $(f^{-1})'(x)=\frac{1}{f(f^{-1}(x))}$, then they are the inverse of the other.

Answer (score 7):

Here "$\log$" means $\log_e$.

In general, $\log_a b$ is the exponent $x$ such that $a^x=b$.

So, $\log_e e^2$ is the exponent $x$ such that $e^x=e^2$.

Evidently that is $2$.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. That really cleared up my confusion with the concept.

Answer (score 3):

If log stands for logarithm to base $e$ then $\log x=y$ is equivalent to $x=e^{y}$. From this definition it is obvious that $log (e^{2})=2$.

Comment: Yes this is the *definition* of logarithm.

Comment: @AdamRubinson There is no 'the' definition of logarithm. There are many equivalent statements that could define it and different authors can use and do use different definitions to their convenience.

Comment: Ok sure, I should have said, this is *a* definition of logarithm. I was trying to make an emphatic point at the expense of being technically handwavy/incorrect. Probably this is bad practice, so fair enough for correcting me.

Answer (score 1):

Compute
$$
A := \int_1^{e^2}\frac{dt}{t}.
$$
Note $A = B+C$, where
$$
B= \int_1^{e}\frac{dt}{t}\qquad C=\int_e^{e^2}\frac{dt}{t}
$$
Of course $B = 1$, that is the definition of $e$.
For $C$, substitute $t=es,\; dt = e\;ds$ to see
$$
C = \int_e^{e^2}\frac{dt}{t} = \int_1^e \frac{e\;ds}{e\;s} = B = 1.
$$
Therefore $A = B+C = 1+1 = 2$.

Answer (score 0):

First of all.  By $\log$ the mean natural log which is often (some could even argue usually) written as $\ln$.  It does not mean $\log_{10}$ or log base $10$ which is often (some could even argue usually) what $\log$ is assumed to mean.

Now $\log_b a$ (what $b > 0$ and $b \ne 1$ and $a > 0$ is defined to be "whatever it takes to get $b^{??????} = a$, then that value is what $\log_b a$ is *defined* to be.

So as a result $b^{\log_b a} =a$.  Always.

Basically just remember (assuming $b > 0$ and $b \ne 1$ and $a >0$) that $b^k =a \iff \log_b a = k$.  That's a definition.

So if $\log 2 = \log_e 2 = \log 2$ then $e^{\log 2} =2$ by definition.

.......

Sort of.

In calculus we usually start with defining $Ln(x) = \int_1^x \frac 1t dt$ and $exp(x)$ as the inverse of $Ln(x)$.  That is if $Ln(k) = x$ then $exp(x)$ is that value $k$ that makes $\int_1^k\frac 1t dt = x$.

Then $e = exp(1) = \lim(1+\frac 1n)^n$. and as it all works out (... ignore my crazy wandwaving...) that $e^x = exp(x)$ and $\log_e x = Ln(x) = \int_1^x \frac 1t dt$. and that way we can defint what $b^x$ means for irrational real $x$.